# Draw shadow under NSImage

Tags: cocoa, shadow, nsimage, nscell

Currently I'm drawing an NSImage in a custom NSCell like so:

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)theCellFrame inView:(NSView *)theControlView {
    // roundedCornerImage creates a new NSImage with rounded corners, rather than clipping.
    [[anIcon roundedCornerImage:5] drawInRect:anIconBox fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
}
```

Very simply I'm wondering how to draw an image underneath it. On the iPhone, I would do this by using: `CGContextSetShadow (currentContext, CGSizeMake(1, -1), 2)`; just before drawing the UIImage, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do it on the Mac.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the [`NSShadow`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSShadow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. `CGContextSetShadow` also exists on the Mac, but it's slightly more difficult to get your hands on the context itself.